Western where one shoots at spurs of another, making them spin
Ok, I know this is very thin, but I thought I'll give it a try...
I'm trying to find the tittle of the first Western movie I really saw as a kid – and when I say "saw", I mean that I saw about 10 minutes of it before going back to sleep.
I'm from Norway, and I grew up with only one(!) license-fee financed (no adds!) TV channel, the State-owned NRK.  I don't remember exactly when, but between 1983 and 1985, they started supplementing their "Monday movie" with "night cinema" on Saturday (well, the night to Sunday). The first movie was "The Marathon Man" with Dustin Hoffman.  The movie I'm after was the first Western/Cowboy movie they aired in this slot.
NRK was never eager to air the latest movies, so it probably was a few (probably several) years old.  However, I don't have the impression it was old (40s, 50s or 60s) – though I could be mistaken here.  If it was from the 80s, it must have been from the very early 80s... But I've always sort of had the impression that it was from the 70s – probably mid to late.
Anyway, the one scene I do remember is two cowboys standing facing each other – pretty far apart.  It's possible they're about to duel.  I think they're standing on a rather empty field, or perhaps outside a town.  It may have been a very wide street (or just filmed that way), but I don't think it was your typical duel-in-narrow-street-in-the-middle-of-town.
One of them outdraws the other, and shoots several shots at the other's spurs which starts spinning like tiny wheels.  There were many repeated shots – the scene makes quite a number of it.
Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Hm, do you remember if this maybe was something like a comedy/funny-western-setting? Sounds familar to me, but reminds me more on a Terence Hill Western . But not sure if i am right and cant remember which one..

@kl78  I'm not sure, as I mentione, I saw very little of it.  Though I don't think it was a comedy, and certainly not slap-sticky like Terence Hill & Bud Spencer.  It may have had funny moments - and I'll admit spur-shooting isn't really realistic - but I think it was a serious (non-comic) movie... perhaps even a bit dark/violent, since it was aired in that slot.

Sounds like one of the spaghetti westerns; I've a vague memory of having seen what you are describing and haven't seen THAT many westerns (especially not from those decades) ( A Fistful of Dollars (1964), For a Few Dollars More (1965) and The Good, the Bad and the Ugly (1966)) - Or again it reminds me of a scene where Gene Hackman 'toys' with a man by 'making him dance' in a duel either in Unforgiven(92) or The Quick and the Dead(95) , its a lot more recent though

Sure does bring to mind a Terrance hill western I seem to remember it as a scene in the one where he and his adversary also shoot holes in one another's hats , I'm at a loss for the title but I think it might be an early one. Wish I could remember as I'm a huge fan of those movies and have been since seeing them yrs ago as a teenager good luck and since it's late at night here I'm operating at only 1/3 speed. I don't remember if sass has clubs in your area. But here in New Mexico,USA founders ranch and sass' headquarters location guests are always welcome to observe at our club Rio Grande Regu
